# Excel formula quotation symbol meaning

Tags: excel, symbols

what do the quotation symbols mean in this equation? I cant find a simple straight answer.

```
=IF(K25="","",L24+K25)
```

Comment: this question belongs more on superuser

Answer (score 3):

`""` means empty, or technically an empty value/string.

If K25 is empty (`""`) then return an empty string (`""`). Otherwise, add.

An alternative is using `ISBLANK()`, `=IF(ISBLANK(K25),"",L24+K25)`.

Note that `=A1=""` will return `TRUE` if a formula returns `""` but using `ISBLANK` on that same cell will return `FALSE`, since technically the cell is not blank.

[image]

In the above, `B2` is empty.  `B3` is a formula, `=""`.

Answer (score 2):

Quotes with nothing in them, "", indicates nothing, or a blank cell. The formula says that if cell k25 is empty, then return no value. If k25 is not empty, then perform the calcuation l24+l25.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Just got the "ah ha i get it" moment LOL

Answer (score 1):

they mean nothing, an empty cell. If k25 is empty, return nothing.